# What is the name of the matrix operation "$\;\overrightarrow{y}\;$"?

Tags: matrices, notation, matrix-equations

I was doing some stuff for my computer science class, and it was talking about the vectorized form of unregularized logistic regression and I'm pretty bad at matrices and when I saw this symbol I was completely stumped. (I'm sorry for not pasting the text it wasn't coming out right so I am using an image)

Here is an image for what I am asking. The notation is above the y:

[image]

sorry for having not many specifics.
Thanks for any help you could give me!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\large\vec y$ denotes a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\large \vec y$ denotes a vector; for example, $\large\vec y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ is an $n$-tuple in $\Bbb R^n$,

where $y_1,y_2,...,y_n\in\Bbb R$.  Such a vector could be multiplied by a scalar and/or a matrix.